# How to delete or merge near-duplicate names using OpenRefine?

Tags: duplicates, data-cleaning, openrefine

I have 250,000 rows of first and last names. The first and last names are in separate columns, but they can be inconsistent e.g:

John Smith
John-Smith
John M. Smith
Jhon Smith

How do I identify these near-duplicates and remove/merge them using openrefine?

I tried using sorting then using blank down, but it only appears to work for exact match duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

OpenRefine has implemented several clustering methods to identify and merge data. Check out the [OpenRefine documentation](https://openrefine.org/docs/manual/cellediting#cluster-and-edit) for details.

Each clustering method has its own benefits and weaknesses so it usually is recommended to combine them and use several iterations.

In your case I would use the following workflow:

1. [Fingerprinting](https://openrefine.org/docs/manual/cellediting#fingerprinting)
2. [N-Gram Fingerprinting](https://openrefine.org/docs/manual/cellediting#fingerprinting)
3. Maybe a [phonetic algorithm](https://openrefine.org/docs/manual/cellediting#phonetic-clustering) (probably [methaphone](https://openrefine.org/docs/manual/cellediting#metaphone3-fingerprinting)), but it might produce mainly false positives with names.
4. [Levenshtein](https://openrefine.org/docs/manual/cellediting#levenshtein-distance)
5. Levenshtein with smaller block size and bigger distance
6. [PPM](https://openrefine.org/docs/manual/cellediting#ppm)

Answer (score 0):

Building on @b2m answer, you can

1. Create a new column by [concatenating](https://openrefine.org/docs/manual/columnediting#join-columns) your first and last name
2. Use the clustering function described by @b2m on the new column
3. Once you have corrected all the spelling variations you can use the bank down to remove duplicates. See the detailed walkthrough on [how to remove duplicate](https://kb.refinepro.com/2011/08/remove-duplicate.html)